Dynamically adjusting bones based on Shape Key adjustments
I am trying to make a customizable body in Blender, and I am using Shape Keys to manipulate the scaling of body parts, i.e. making the arms and legs thicker and longer. However when I alter the mesh from the default shape in a way that it greatly differs from the default appearance, posing it becomes wonky, with the elbows not bending properly for example if the arms get longer. It is possible to mitigate the issue a bit by scaling the bone structure manually but I am wondering if there is a way to do this correction process in a more automatic way.
